# What is difference between let , const and var in case of variable shadowing /re declaration in different scope?

Tags: javascript, constants, var, let, hoisting

Please check below 2 code snippets the difference is redeclaring as const/let and var in foo function.

for var, it executes but for const and let it throughs error.

Please tell me why it behaves differently.

```
Below code does not through any error as a is declared as var
var a=12; //Global variable
foo(); //hoisting 
function foo() {
    console.log("a="+a);
    var a=13;
    console.log("a="+a);
    if(true) {
        const a=89;
        console.log("in block="+ a);
    }
    var a=90;    //no error
    console.log("a="+a);    
}
```

Below code throughs variable declaration error "a has already been declared"

```
var a=12; //Global variable
foo(); //hoisting 
function foo() {
    console.log("a="+a);
    var a=13;
    console.log("a="+a);
    if(true) {
        const a=89;
        console.log("in block="+ a);
    }
    let a=90;    //Or const a :: error
    console.log("a="+a);    
}
```

Comment: With `var` you can and with `let` and `const` you can't -> "_variable shadowing /re declaration in different scope?_" But, in the case of this code `var a` outside the function is still in scope within the function - you are not shadowing but redeclaring (which is legal with `var` but not with `const` & `let`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understood the difference :)